# ng-class on Angular 1.5 component element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm converting some directives to components, and was trying to eliminate the extra "wrapping" element since `replace: true` doesn't work anymore. However, the old wrapping element had an ng-class on it.

```
<some-directive>
    <div ng-class="{classOne: someDirectiveCtrl.isClassOne}">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</some-directive>
```

In that example, with `replace: true`, the div becomes the "wrapping" element.

```
<div ng-class="{classOne: someDirectiveCtrl.isClassOne}">
     <p>...</p>
</div>
```

So...

#### Question

Is there a way to access information in a components controller in order to add classes to the component's element?

ie

```
<some-component ng-class="{classOne: someComponentCtrl.isClassOne}">
    <p>...</p>
</some-component>
```

I'd rather not put functions for the component in the parent controller, and I'd like to have the classes listed in the HTML.

Comment: This might help https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives

Comment: I see nothing in there that answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components always use isolate scope, which is inaccessible from the outside world. You’ll have to give up the nice declarative approach that ng-class provides and use the available $element in the component controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-controller` instead of `ng-class`. Assign controller into `ng-controller` and then use your class.

Comment: Would that create an extra instance of the component's controller?

Answer (score 0):

We gave up and reorganized the html and css so that it wasn't an issue. :(